# Set value of input html string with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have snippet of HTML in a string like this:

```
var htmlString = '<input type="text" id="someID" name="someID">';
```

How do I, with jQuery, set its value so that the HTML ends up like this:

```
'<input type="text" id="someID" name="someID" value="newValue">';
```

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$(htmlString).attr("value", "newValue");
```

But this will return jQuery object, not string. You can add it to DOM.

```
$(htmlString).attr("value", "newValue").appendTo("body"); // you can give any element instead of body
```

EDIT :

You can use @idor_brad's method. That is the best way or

```
var htmlString = '<input type="text" id="someID" name="someID">';

var $htmlString = $(htmlString);
$htmlString.attr("value1", "newValue1");
$htmlString.attr("value2", "newValue2");
$htmlString.attr("value3", "newValue3");

console.log($htmlString.get(0).outerHTML);
```

or

```
var htmlString = '<input type="text" id="someID" name="someID">';

var $htmlString = $(htmlString);
$htmlString.attr("value1", "newValue1");
$htmlString.attr("value2", "newValue2");
$htmlString.attr("value3", "newValue3");

console.log($("<div>").append($htmlString).html());
```

Comment: I know that... I thought maybe you had found a clever way to do it without using the DOM. Oh well :)

Comment: Do you want to retrieve the final string without using DOM ? That is also possible

Comment: That gets me most of the way there.  How do I get the HTML string back out of the jQuery object?

Answer (score 6):

You would first need to add your element to the DOM (ie to your web page). For example:

```
$(".container").append(htmlString);
```

Then you can access your `input` as a jquery object and add the value attribute like so:

```
$("#someID").val("newValue");
```

[**-- See Demo --**](http://jsfiddle.net/HSKAT/)

Answer (score 4):

You just want to manipulate the string, right? There are a lot of ways to skin this cat, but

```
var newString = htmlString.replace('>', ' value="newValue">');
```

Answer (score 1):

After the dom ready, append your input to body and then grab the input with id = "someID" and set its value to newValue

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $("body").append(htmlString);
       $("#someID").val("newValue");
    });
```

Comment: This is the most elegant solution in my case, as my html is complex.