# JQuery html string input box

Tags: jquery, html, string, forms, input

I have this function:

```
function msj(str) {
//    display = document.getElementById("txt"); // DOM
//    nodo = document.createTextNode(str);
//    display.replaceChild(nodo,display.firstChild);
$("#txt").html(str); // jQuery
}
```

The message is displayed here:

```
<div id="txt">Guess the number between 1 and 10</div>
```

Then, I want to display the message into a input text form. Anyone knows how to do it?

Many thanks.

Comment: I know! But I won't tell you until you tell us [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
<input type="text" id="txt" />

function msj(str) {
  $("#txt").val(str); // jQuery
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an input text element with `id=input-txt` then you could do

```
$("#input-txt").val(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery

```
function msj(str){
  $("#txt").val(str);
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="inputField" id="txt" />
```

- [Relevant](http://api.jquery.com/val/)
- [Relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088467/get-value-in-input-text-box)
- [Relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11760418/replace-input-value-val-with-jquery)
- [Relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802999/set-value-to-hidden-input-with-jquery)
- [Relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008234/set-value-of-input-html-string-with-jquery)
- [Really Relevant](https://www.google.com/search?q=JQuery+html+string+input+box)

Okay, maybe that's a bit overkill with relevant links that answer your question, but they all answer your question.